# Professional quality sound recording at home

Tags: audio-recording

I have purchased a Blue Yeti microphone for recording my screencast. My room where I do the recording is adjacent to the main road and  the road is also steep. Hence vehicles put the accelerator and honk continuously which reflects in the recorded audio.

Is there a way I could avoid these noises completely to get a professional recordings? Currently my way is to sit late night when there are no vehicles and do my recordings.

Please let me know if there is any alternative.

Comment: The professionals invest money in studios, which are one of the largest portions of the cost of professional recordings. The studios are highly sound-controlled and located in ideal places away from ambient noises.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to offer a complete solution to your problem. Unwanted noise can be difficult to deal with, which is why in a professional scenario most people would opt for a sound-proofed studio when they can.

Having said that there are some things that might help improve your sound. For one, make sure your Blue Yeti is set to its cardioid polar pattern. This will mean that to some extent the mic will reject sounds coming from behind it. Also you should consider your distance from the mic. If you are too far away from it you'll naturally need to have the volume set higher, which will make the outside noises louder. I did a quick skim read of the Blue Microphones website and they recommend you be roughly 6 inches from the Yeti, and certainly no more than 1 foot away. In your recording software it might also help to use an EQ to try and reduce the background noise, but this will be a delicate balance between reducing unwanted noise and affecting the vocal quality.

This will probably not be a perfect fix, but if you haven't already implemented these things, they will probably help out :)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Simon K said: make sure you use a [pop killer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pop_filter). Without such a screen, you'll always get sound problems with large-diaphragm mics at short distance. With it, you can get the mic closer than an inch to the mouth, which really helps the signal-to-noise ratio – though it's still nowhere as good as in a properly soundproofed room, so if you're serious about this you should definitely find a better place to record your stuff.